# XSL, variable for number of elements

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, count

I have to create a variable in my xsl document that will count the elements in my xml file and then show this number in the final output. Here I think I did the variable declaration correctly, well probably not. How do create this variable correctly and then "print it" in the html part
thanks

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Albumy Burzum</title>

            <style type="text/css">

            h2 { font-size: 40px; font-family: arial; color: #000000;  }

            </style>


        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>Albumy Burzum</h2>
             <table border="5">
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>year</th>
                    <th>genre</th>
                    <th>label</th>
                    <th>songs_number</th>
                    <th>link</th>

                </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </table>

        <h3>Number of elements:</h3>


        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>





<xsl:attribute-set name="reference">
    <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="link"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<xsl:template match="link">

    <xsl:element name="a" use-attribute-sets="reference"><xsl:value-of select="link"/></xsl:element>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="album">
  <tr> 
    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="genre"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="label"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="songs_number"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="link"/></td>

  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="countElements">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(album)"/>

</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't even shown us the XML input structure and explained which elements you want to count but if you replace `<h3>Number of elements:</h3>` with `<h3>Number of elements: <xsl:value-of select="count(//album)"/></h3>` then you should get the output of the count of any `album` elements in the document, completely without using a variable.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I just figured it out